# How to parse wrapper class

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, community, integration, callout

I have below wrapper class:
public class GitDeployHistroryWrapper {

```
public class Details {
    public List<ComponentFailures> componentFailures  {get;set;} 
    public List<ComponentSuccesses> componentSuccesses  {get;set;} 
    public String retrieveResult  {get;set;} 
    public List<ComponentFailures> allComponentMessages  {get;set;} 
    public RunTestResult runTestResult  {get;set;} 
}

public String id  {get;set;} 
public String validatedDeployRequestId  {get;set;} 
public String deployOptions  {get;set;} 
public DeployResult deployResult  {get;set;} 

public class DeployResult {
    public String id  {get;set;} 
    public String messages  {get;set;} 
    public String retrieveResult  {get;set;} 
    public Boolean success  {get;set;} 
    public Boolean checkOnly  {get;set;} 
    public Boolean ignoreWarnings  {get;set;} 
    public Boolean rollbackOnError  {get;set;} 
    public String status  {get;set;} 
    public Integer numberComponentsDeployed  {get;set;} 
    public Integer numberComponentsTotal  {get;set;} 
    public Integer numberComponentErrors  {get;set;} 
    public Integer numberTestsCompleted  {get;set;} 
    public Integer numberTestsTotal  {get;set;} 
    public Integer numberTestErrors  {get;set;} 
    public Details details  {get;set;} 
    public String createdDate {get;set;} 
    public String startDate {get;set;} 
    public String lastModifiedDate {get;set;} 
    public String completedDate {get;set;} 
    public String errorStatusCode {get;set;} 
    public String errorMessage {get;set;} 
    public String stateDetail {get;set;} 
    public String createdBy {get;set;} 
    public String createdByName {get;set;} 
    public String canceledBy {get;set;} 
    public String canceledByName {get;set;} 
    public Boolean done {get;set;} 
    public String runTestResult {get;set;} 
    public Boolean runTestsEnabled {get;set;} 
}

public class Successes {
    public String namespace {get;set;}
    public String name {get;set;}
    public String methodName {get;set;}
    public String id {get;set;}
    //public String time {get;set;}
    public String seeAllData {get;set;}
        
}
public class Failures {
    public String type {get;set;}
    public String namespace {get;set;}
    public String name {get;set;}
    public String methodName {get;set;}
    public String stackTrace {get;set;}
    public String id {get;set;}
    public String seeAllData {get;set;}
    public String packageName {get;set;}
   // public String time {get;set;}
    
}

public class RunTestResult {
    public List<Successes> successes {get;set;} 
    public List<Failures> failures {get;set;} 
    public Double totalTime {get;set;} 
    public String apexLogId {get;set;} 
    public Integer numTestsRun {get;set;} 
    public List<Successes> flowCoverage {get;set;} 
    public List<Successes> codeCoverage {get;set;} 
    public Integer numFailures {get;set;} 
    public List<Successes> codeCoverageWarnings {get;set;} 
    public List<Successes> flowCoverageWarnings {get;set;} 
}
public class allComponentMessages{
    public String componentType {get;set;} 
    public String fileName {get;set;} 
    public String fullName {get;set;} 
    public String id {get;set;} 
    public String problem {get;set;} 
    public Boolean success {get;set;} 
    public Boolean warning {get;set;} 
    public Boolean created {get;set;} 
    public Boolean changed {get;set;} 
    public Boolean deleted {get;set;} 
    public Integer lineNumber {get;set;} 
    public Integer columnNumber {get;set;} 
    public Boolean requiresProductionTestRun {get;set;} 
    public String createdDate {get;set;} 
    public Boolean knownPackagingProblem {get;set;} 
    public Boolean forPackageManifestFile {get;set;} 
    public String problemType {get;set;} 
}   

public class ComponentFailures {
    public String componentType {get;set;} 
    public String fileName {get;set;} 
    public String fullName {get;set;} 
    public String id {get;set;} 
    public String problem {get;set;} 
    public Boolean success {get;set;} 
    public Boolean warning {get;set;} 
    public Boolean created {get;set;} 
    public Boolean changed {get;set;} 
    public Boolean deleted {get;set;} 
    public Integer lineNumber {get;set;} 
    public Integer columnNumber {get;set;} 
    public Boolean requiresProductionTestRun {get;set;} 
    public String createdDate {get;set;} 
    public Boolean knownPackagingProblem {get;set;} 
    public Boolean forPackageManifestFile {get;set;} 
    public String problemType {get;set;} 
}
public class ComponentSuccesses{
    
    public String componentType {get;set;} 
    public String fileName {get;set;} 
    public String fullName {get;set;} 
    public String id {get;set;} 
    public String problem {get;set;} 
    public Boolean success {get;set;} 
    public Boolean warning {get;set;} 
    public Boolean created {get;set;} 
    public Boolean changed {get;set;} 
    public Boolean deleted {get;set;} 
    public Integer lineNumber {get;set;} 
    public Integer columnNumber {get;set;} 
    public Boolean requiresProductionTestRun {get;set;} 
    public String createdDate {get;set;} 
    public Boolean knownPackagingProblem {get;set;} 
    public Boolean forPackageManifestFile {get;set;} 
    public String problemType {get;set;} 
}


public static GitDeployHistroryWrapper parse(String json) {
    return (GitDeployHistroryWrapper) System.JSON.deserialize(json, GitDeployHistroryWrapper.class);
}
```

}

**I am deserializing response like below in my main class:**
GitDeployHistroryWrapper callList= (GitDeployHistroryWrapper)JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(), GitDeployHistroryWrapper.class);

I want list of ComponentSuccesses to return from my main class method.
How can i achieve this?
Pls help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 GitDeployHistroryWrapper resParams = new GitDeployHistroryWrapper();
 if(res.getStatusCode() == 200){
    resParam = GitDeployHistroryWrapper.parse(res.getbody()); 
    return resParam.deployResult.details.componentSuccesses;
  }
```

Comment: my wrapper class is a separate class so when i am using return resParam.componentSuccesses; its throwing Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: componentSuccesses at line 18 column 31

Comment: try this - return resParam.deployResult.details.componentSuccesses;

Comment: I've downvoted this because it's a _code dump_ (where you provide code, but no explanation). Explaining _what_ the issue is and _why_ your solution works is as important as the solution itself. Explaining things helps to build an understanding of how things work, and knowing how things work makes it easier to solve other problems.

Comment: its is  working thanks!!